# Perl split function for the first word

Tags: perl, split

I am completely new to the Perl programming.
I am trying the split function.
Here is my code:

```
#!perl;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @sections = ("Hard Drive", "Multi Drive");
foreach my $secname (sort @sections) 
{
    my $file_name=split / /, $secname;
    print $file_name;
}
```

so I am trying to get the output like only second word only.

output is 
`22`

The expected output is:

```
drive
drive
```

Here I am trying to get second word but it is not giving the expected output.

Please anyone suggest and help me.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html `Splits the string EXPR into a list of strings and returns the list in list context, or the size of the list in scalar context.` `my ($file_name)=split / /, $secname;` <== list context imposed by parens on the left side of assignment.

Comment: http://perlmaven.com/scalar-and-list-context-in-perl

Comment: Also note your output would be `Drive`, not `drive` unless you use the `lc` builtin on it.

Comment: @Сухой27 here i can get the first words of each..wat about second word?

Comment: Values are populated from left to right. my (undef, $file_name)=split / /, $secname;

Comment: `undef` what is that doing?

Comment: You can think of it as empty placeholder for first word/value which you want to skip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you get unexpected behaviour from Perl function, your first step should be to read the documentation for that function. The [documentation for `split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) says this:

> Splits the string EXPR into a list of strings and returns the list in
>   list context, or the size of the list in scalar context.

So, in scalar context, `split` returns the number of element in the list, not the actual list. Your code:

```
my $file_name = split / /, $secname;
```

is calling `split` in scalar context (as you are assigning the result to a scalar variable). In order to get the result that you want, yo need to call `split` in list context. There are a number of ways to achieve this.

```
# Assign to an array, take the second element
my @bits = split / /, $secname;
my $file_name = $bits[1];

# Use a list slice to only get the value that you want
my $file_name = (split / /, $secname)[1];

# Use a list assignment
my (undef, $file_name) = split / /, $secname);
```

Answer (score 2):

Split returns a list of strings in list context only.

As mentioned in the comments above, you can thus get the strings by using list context.

For example, store them all in an array:

```
my @split_string = split / /, $secname;
my $wanted = $split_string[1]; # get the string you want (here, second)
```

If you do not need them later, you can also use an anonymous array for this,
saving yourself a variable:

```
my $wanted = (split / /,$secname)[1];
```

Most functions in perl are context-sensitive, i.e. return different values whether called in list or in scalar context, the return values are usually quite sensible when you think about it, but it takes some getting used to.

Comment: Pedantically, that's not an anonymous array. It's a list slice.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, you are, of course, perfectly correct. I will leave my answer as is, though, to not mess up this post.

Answer (score 1):

As @Сухой27 has [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936393/perl-split-function-for-the-first-word#comment51783715_31936393) and from [split doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

> Splits the string EXPR into a list of strings and returns the list in list context, or the size of the list in scalar context.

so you can do like this by creating list context:

```
my @sections = ("Hard Drive", "Multi Drive");

foreach my $secname (sort @sections) 
{
    my ($first, $file_name) = split / /, $secname;
    print $file_name, "\n";
}
```

or if you don't want extra variable just define it as `undef`:

```
my (undef, $file_name) = split / /, $secname;
```

or assigning into an array:

```
my @file_name = split / /, $secname;
print $file_name[1], "\n";
```

or you can use list slice:

```
my $file_name = (split / /, $secname)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

split converts scalar to list. You tried to split the each values of an list.

The output `22` results because, it displays the total number of scalar in an list.

For example

```
@ar = qw(1 4);
$aa = @ar;
print $aa;
```

It results `2`. The same think was rises in your problem.

So you store the splitting value into an array. And the print the expected output by the index key of array.

Try this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @sections = ("Hard Drive", "Multi Drive");
foreach my $secname (sort @sections) 
{
    my @file_name=split / /, $secname;
    print $file_name[1],"\n";
}
```

Comment: No. `split` does not convert a scalar to an array. It converts a scalar to a list. Lists and arrays are not the same thing in Perl. Arrays have nothing to do with this example. You get the number of elements in the list because that is what `split` is [documented](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to return in scalar context.

Comment: You over-corrrected :-) You store the results of the `split` in an array. I've edited your post to say that. Hope you don't mind.